# Unexpected output in expession using pre-increment

Tags: c++, pre-increment

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int numb = 2;
    numb = ++numb + ++numb;
    cout << numb;
}
```

Why is the output 8?

Comment: The output is 8 because the compiler is allowed to increment `numb` two times before using it in the assignment expression. Which doesn't mean that it has to. This behaviour is undefined in the C++ standard and you should never write such code.

Comment: It's undefined as the operands of `+` are unsequenced. `numb = ++numb << ++numb;` would be well-defined